# How to get column name with max value across multiple columns

Tags: sql, sas

I have the following data, I am using proc sql in SAS.

```
ID  Col_1 Col_2 Col_3
1   100   110   120
```

I want to get

```
ID Max_Col
1  Col_3
```

Comment: You should post what you've tried and where you're having issues. If you also specifically say SQL vs DATA you should explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a SQL solution, since the problem lends itself better to a SAS data step. `VNAME()` also doesn't work in SAS SQL.

Assuming you're using SAS then you can use a combination of the `VNAME`, `MAX` ,and `WHICHN` functions. What would you want to happen if you had duplicates for the maximum value?

```
 data want;
 set have;

 array col(3) col_1-col_3;

 index_of_max=whichn(max(of col(*)), of col(*));
 variable_name=vname(col(index_of_max));

 run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a Case would do your task

```
select ID, case when Col_1 >= Col_2 then 'Col_1'
                when Col_2 <= Col_3 then 'Col_3'
                else 'Col_2'
                end as MAX_Col
      from [TABLENAME];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the LARGEST function:

```
ID, LARGEST(Col_1, Col_2, Col_3)
```